# Amazon SES: image as a background

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have a question regarding SES templating,

I have an email template with HTML and I want a background-image:

```
<!-- Main Header Container-->
<tr style="background-image:url('*HERE*');" height="200">
```

this approach would always leave it blank, whether I import a file to the URL or just a static URL link.

Why is this?

Also, if anyone knows: 
 - do SES templates support classes? (cause mine usually are not detected)
 - do SES templates support the feature like grid / flex (cause for me no)

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

By some reason, a plugin was blocking the image